# Button color change to show visitor is on current page

Tags: css, wordpress, button

I am trying to make a sidebar button's background color change to let the visitor know which page they are currently on. I've tried searching the web for similar answers and applying them to my code but have yet been able to get it to work. I am using WordPress, CSS, & PHP/HTML if that helps any. Below is one of the buttons code:

```css
.button-goldGrey {
  color: #231f20;
  border: 1px solid #231f20;
}

.button-goldGrey:hover {
  background-color: #ccb086;
}
```

```html
<a class="button-side button-goldGrey" href="Page1">LINK 1</a>
<a class="button-side button-goldGrey" href="Page1">LINK 1</a>
<a class="button-side button-goldGrey" href="Page1">LINK 1</a>
```

And I put this JSFiddle together if you prefer that: https://jsfiddle.net/zerojjc/huxznj7m/2/

Comment: CSS alone isn't enough to highlight the current page. You'll need some PHP to know which page is currently on display and act accordingly (eg. add a `.current` class to the element.)

Comment: You can use the `:active` selector to select and style the active link.

Comment: @AmineKOUIS - That's actually incorrect. If you look at the docs for the [`:active` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active), it actually represents the element currently being "activated" by the user (effectively, being clicked/pressed upon). Note this is similar but fundamentally different than [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks for your response, but i'm unsure how to do that with PHP.

Comment: @Xhynk Yea I tried using :active before and found it didn't work for this.

Comment: @Zerojjc are you using a Page Builder to create [this page](https://clientfirstalliance.com/client-first-alliance/pwa-wealth-management/) or are you editing theme files directly?

Comment: Nevermind, from a comment you left below it seems you're editing PHP files directly. Check my answer below and, if it helped, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have any questions you're welcome to ask as well.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned on my comment to your question, CSS alone can't do this. You'll need some PHP to achieve this.

Assuming you can use PHP and that you can edit your theme's files, WordPress has a function called [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) that you can use to add a new CSS class to your buttons.

For example:

CSS:

```
.button-goldGrey {
  color: #231f20;
  border: 1px solid #231f20;
}

.button-goldGrey:hover,
.button-goldGrey.current {
  background-color: #ccb086;
}
```

PHP:

```
<a class="button-side button-goldGrey<?php echo (is_page('pwa-wealth-management')) ? ' current' : ''; ?>" href="Page1">PWA Wealth Management</a>
<a class="button-side button-goldGrey<?php echo (is_page('wilder-co')) ? ' current' : ''; ?>" href="Page1">Wilder & Company CPA's</a>
<a class="button-side button-goldGrey<?php echo (is_page('the-nichols-law-group')) ? ' current' : ''; ?>" href="Page1">The Nichols Law Group</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page name using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` then you can just add proper classes in each `<li>` element and then later highlight the corresponding link  with some CSS like the code below.

CSS code :

```
.button-goldGrey {
  color: #231f20;
  border: 1px solid #231f20;
}

.button-goldGrey:hover {
  background-color: #ccb086;
}
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

PHP + HTML code :

```
<?php
     $activePage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
  <ul>
   <li class="<?php ($activePage == 'Page1') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a class="button-side button-goldGrey" href="Page1">LINK 1</a></li>
   <li class="<?php ($activePage == 'Page2') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a class="button-side button-goldGrey" href="Page2">LINK 1</a></li>
   <li class="<?php ($activePage == 'Page3') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a class="button-side button-goldGrey" href="Page3">LINK 1</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It appears there are some issues with this code, here is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/LekcgOH.png

Comment: I'm sorry but this still does not appear to be working. There aren't any errors, but the .active class doesn't appear on the <li> on the current page.

Comment: Don't forget to change the page name in order to match the current page, so can you put `var_dump($activePage);die();` juste below `$activePage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` and tell me the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just CSS3 ! Just put the CSS attribute directly into the concerned <a> element, such as:

```html
<ul class="nav_links">
  <li><a style="color: #ff6511" href="page.html">Accueil</a></li>
  <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tarif</a></li>
  <li><a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contact</button></a></li>
</ul>
```